# Reach .text section in Pe files

Tags: c++, portable-executable

I am using C++ on linux and i don't use windows.h library

I see the following example on github:
https://gist.github.com/djhaskin987/d1860a7d98193913bcfa#file-get_exe_version-c-L30

```
const char *raw = buf + READ_DWORD(sec + 20);
const char *realSec = raw + (rvaInDataDir - virtualArdressSec);
```

i want to reach the .text section and i see rvaInDataDir for .edata , .idata, .pdata ,.rsrc ...  But i don't see rva for .text inDataDir. How can i get the RVA?

Comment: PE32 does not demand specific names for sections, ".text" is merely a common convention.  It is not necessarily present.  You have to iterate the [section table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/debug/pe-format#section-table-section-headers) to find it, the table entry specifies the RVA.

Comment: Unfortunately firstly i try only section's RVA. This method bring me only ".�9.text" :(  . And i read another doc and they say that i have to turn RVA to offset and i saw this example but this does not enough for me.